# Connected to wifi,But no internet

Tags: wireless, server, network-manager, dns

I am using ubuntu 13.10(64 bit) with 8GB ram and core i5 processor.

Recently my service provider created a new wifi connection(name starting with AP) and gave me address,netmask and gateway ip to be put on IPv4 settings tab on AP connection.
And i did what he asked.Then he asked for my mac address and i supplied it(My MAC address is eth1 - cc:52:af:9a:33:10).

But since then i can connect to wifi(it shows signal streangth and a message as connected) but no internet connection.

Service provider says its something wrong with my OS since all the others work it fine.It's true.I checked with one of my friend and it worked fine.

And i can connect to other wifi networks(such as wifi hotspot created by my phone).I only have problem with this connection.

Following might be helpful.

Address - 192.168.0.19
Netmask - 255.255.255.0
Gateway - 192.168.0.2
DNS servers - 8.8.8.8

Output of ifconfig -

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 2c:27:d7:d7:96:85  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr cc:52:af:9a:33:10  
      inet addr:192.168.0.19  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:13384 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:13961
      TX packets:12905 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:10299513 (10.2 MB)  TX bytes:3678376 (3.6 MB)
      Interrupt:16
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:490 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:490 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:31602 (31.6 KB)  TX bytes:31602 (31.6 KB)
```

Output of iwconfig -

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.
eth1      IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"AP_6BBD32"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: E8:94:F6:6B:BD:32  
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Output of pinging gateway ip (pinging to my own ip works fine) -

```
$: ping 192.168.0.2
PING 192.168.0.2 (192.168.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.19 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable 
From 192.168.0.19 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.19 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Output of pinging DNS server -

```
$: ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.19 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.19 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.19 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

resolv.conf

```
$: cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Please help me with this,I've stuck with this for days now.
Thank you.

Comment: Hi & Welcome to **AU**. You're referring to a WiFi issue but I don't see any `wlan` adapters or connectivity while I can only see `eth` (wired) connections. Your question seems to be confusing, could you please be more clear to assist better. :)

Comment: Hello,thanks for replying ;) Yes it doesn't have wlanO,does it mean i cant connect to wifi.But i already connected to other wifi networks using same settings.Do you think it's a driver issue?.

Comment: could you please try `iwconfig` & `route -n` then post the output by editing your question. Also, I'm not sure it says connected may be because of you using manual/static IP's.. not so sure but please post those details too.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you gave to your ISP the MAC address of your ethernet card, not of your WIFI adapter ! He's probably filtering access on this setting.